# I want to add other content with navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-drawer

I am new to android.
I have created a drawer layout using list view (custom list view using base adapter).
 this is my code activity_main.xml. When i run the application i see an empty screen. Listview is working properly. But i just need to add another content in the screen, like mapview or anything else. And i want that content to move when the navigation menu is opened. How to add content other than list view in the below code?

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 </FrameLayout>

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:background="#CECECE"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"></ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FrameLayout` is the one that holds your main content. Create a fragment and its layout, then on your `MainActivity` you add the fragment to the `FrameLayout` like this.

```
 MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
 FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.add(R.id.mainContent, fragment, "fragment").commit()`;
```

Comment: Is MyFragment is a seperate class which extends Fragment??

Comment: I tried creating seperate class and layout for fragment and i am getting these errors     Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction to android.app.FragmentTransaction

Comment: your fragment should extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead of android.app.Fragment.